# Deploying with Visual Studio 2019 to Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am trying to deploy to my Hololens 2 and I'm trying to connect to it via wifi.

I am following the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch1

I also followed the instructions here for connecting via wifi:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio#enabling-developer-mode

1. I am using Master/Arm64/Remote Machine
2. I got the IP address for my Hololens 2 and put it in the Remote Machine Name under Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties - > Debugging -> Remote Machine.
3. For authentication type, I am using "No Authentication".
4. The project builds successfully
5. Problem comes from when I try to deploy.

The error message I am getting is this:

> DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal
> Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode
> is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]

I have confirmed that my machine is in fact turned on when I try to deploy.

Has anyone seen this before?

Do you have any suggestions?

My ip address, on my hololens, is not 127.0.0.1, why does it say that is my IP address? I put something completely different in Configuration Properties -> Debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out what caused this error, but I know how I fixed it.

1. Close out of Visual Studio.
2. Search for a '.suo' file.
3. Delete this file.
4. Open the solution back up.
5. Redeploy the program.

This did it for me.

Solution User Options file (.suo), this file stores user preference settings and is created automatically when Visual Studio saves a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you enter the IP address (machine name) in the active configuration (`Master`/`ARM64` in your case). For the authentication type select the `Universal (Unencrypted Protocol)`, as mentioned in the manual.

Check the IP of the HoloLens 2, which must be entered as the machine name, this can change over time.
You can find the IPv4 address under `Settings` `->` `Network&Internet` `->` `Advanced options` of the Wifi network you are connected to.

Also make sure that the PC from which you deploy the HoloLens 2 and the HoloLens 2 are in the same Wifi network.