# Hololens 2 error when deploying to Remote Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

[My Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQ9B.png)
[My Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8edxo.png)

Hello, I have been making a game in unity with the intent of playing it on the hololens 2. Currently, I only have a cube which I can move, scale and rotate.

When I connect the hololens 2 through a cable, I can deploy it to "Device" and it functions as expected. The problem occurs when I try and connect it wirelessly. I change it to "Remote Machine" and wait for it to build and deploy. When I do, however, I get the errors in the screenshot above.

I entered the Machine Name in the debugging settings, and the authentication type is set to "Universal (Unencrypted Protocol)." The Solution Configuration is set to Release and the Solution Platform is set to ARM64. The Hololens is already paired to my computer, so I don't get promoted to enter a PIN. Developer mode is also enabled on my PC and the hololens. The hololens also has Device Portal and Device Discovery enabled, but my computer does not since I am on Windows 11 Home.

There are two things I can think of that may be causing issues. Firstly, the hololens is on my school's network and is signed in on a school Microsoft account, so some permissions may be blocked. Secondly, the IP Address I found for the Hololens ends in "/16". Nothing on the internet seemed to say anything about a hololens having an IP address that ends in /16, so I don't know if that's the culprit.

One of the solutions I found that seemed to fix the issue I am having said I had to delete a .suo file, but I don't know where to find it. Here is the post: [Deploying with Visual Studio 2019 to Hololens 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606869/deploying-with-visual-studio-2019-to-hololens-2)

I am not a noob at programming, but I am still learning. This is among the most complex projects I've ever worked on so I could have done something completely wrong. I am on windows 11 and I think I installed the correct SDKs, but I may have installed Windows 10 SDKs or something like that. As I said, it works when connected through USB, just not wirelessly.

Thank you in advance for any help, as this has been giving me problems for a while.

Comment: From the error message, Visual Studio did not recognize the IP address of the HoloLens. Please make sure that your device is on the same network as the PC, and you have manually entered the correct IP address by referring to the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#remote-connection. If possible, please provide a screenshot of **Project->Properties->Debugging**. Also, can you access the HoloLens' Device Portal via WIFI?

Comment: Regarding the **.suo** file, it's in **[Your project folder]->.vs->[Your project]->[Visual Studio version]**. I'm not sure if removing it will help, you can try.

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT Hi, Thanks for the response. I attached the image of the project properties panel to the main post. It is currently in ARM64 since it is a unity build, but I have tried x64 and x86 and neither work. Hopefully, you can help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who gets this issue, I found this post here which solved my problem:

[Deployment from unity to Hololens 2 giving error DEP6957](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72043220/deployment-from-unity-to-hololens-2-giving-error-dep6957)